# OpenGL shapes look darker when camera is below them

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I have a problem with rendering my quads in OpenGL. They look darker when translucency is applied, if the camera is below a certain point. How can I fix this? The objects are lots of quads with tiny amounts of Z difference. I have implemented rendering of translucent objects from this webpage: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2750

Render code:

```
double alpha_factor = 0.75;
double alpha_frac = (r_alpha - alpha_factor * r_alpha) / (1.0 - alpha_factor * r_alpha);
double prev_alpha = r_alpha;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

// quintuple pass to get the rendering of translucent objects, somewhat correct
// reverse render order for getting alpha going!
// 1st pass: only depth checks
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
r_alpha = 0;
// send alpha for each pass
// reverse order
drawobjects(RENDER_REVERSE);

// 2nd pass: guaranteed back face display with normal alpha
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
r_alpha = alpha_factor * (prev_alpha + 0.025);
// reverse order
drawobjects(RENDER_REVERSE);

// 3rd pass: depth checked version of fraction of calculated alpha. (minus 1)
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
r_alpha = alpha_frac + 0.025;
// normal order
drawobjects(RENDER_NORMAL);

// 4th pass: same for back face
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
r_alpha = alpha_factor * (prev_alpha + 0.025);
// reverse order
drawobjects(RENDER_REVERSE);

// 5th pass: just put out the entire thing now
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
r_alpha = alpha_frac + 0.025;
// normal order
drawobjects(RENDER_NORMAL);

glDisable(GL_BLEND);

r_alpha = prev_alpha;
```

GLSL shaders:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vPos_ModelSpace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location = 2) in mat4 model_instance;

out vec2 UV;
out float alpha;

flat out uint alpha_mode;

// model + view + proj matrix
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform float v_alpha;
uniform uint v_alpha_mode;

void main() {
    gl_Position = proj * view * model_instance * vec4(vPos_ModelSpace, 1.0);

    // send to frag shader
    UV = vertexUV;
    alpha = v_alpha;
    alpha_mode = v_alpha_mode;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// texture UV coordinate
in vec2 UV;
in float alpha;
flat in uint alpha_mode;

out vec4 color;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D texSampler;

void main() {
    int amode = int(alpha_mode);
    color.rgb = texture(texSampler, UV).rgb;
    color.a = alpha;

    if(amode == 1)
        color.rgb *= alpha;
}
```

Image when problem happens:
[image: How it looks]

Image comparison for how it should look regardless of my position:
[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fades away in the center is because when you look at the infinitely thin sides of the planes they disappear. As for the brightness change top vs bottom, it's due to how your passes treat surface normals. The dark planes are normals facing away from the camera but with no planes facing the camera to lighten them up.

It looks like you are rendering many translucent planes in a cube to estimate a volume. Here is a simple example of a volume rendering: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsG3D3

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/HTML/gpugems/gpugems_ch39.html is a fantastic resource. It explains different ways to render volume, shows how awesome it is. For reference, that last example used a sphere as proxy geometry to raymarch a volume fractal.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for links! Your shader apparently has some errors in it though so it doesn't work but I think I can work that out.

Any idea how I can set my normals properly? I've been trying to look for methods but haven't found anything usable.

Comment: Is there some sort of default behavior that I must override in order for me to change how I treat these normals? No matter how simplified I made the code, it still seems to be the same result. Bottom is darker. @Kyle Bowles

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay. I can see in your shaders you do not discriminate against normals. It must be somewhere in drawobjects(). You should certainly do the "proj * view * model_instance" matrix multiplication on the CPU so it's not done once per vertex (ouch!)